# prepared statements in rails/activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, prepared-statement

does rails activerecord have any support for prepared statements?  best I can tell -no.

Answer (score 4):

Since Rails 3.1 prepared statements in active_record are in place. See this presentation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWOAHIpmLAI by Aaron Patterson.

Comment: the automatic use of prepared statements in 3.1 is database/adapter-dependent. if you're using mysql, prepared statements won't be used automatically.

Comment: Prepared statements start at 9:30: https://youtu.be/kWOAHIpmLAI?t=570.

Answer (score 2):

There are recent patches available to do this for mysql:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3151-mysql-adapter-update-to-enable-use-of-stored-procedures

For Oracle, there are 2 related projects that seem like they do the trick:

- plsql support
  http://github.com/rsim/ruby-plsql
- more goodies when using Oracle and AR, with use of ruby-plsql gem for stored procs
  http://wiki.github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/

Comment: Latest version of rails 2.3.5 has better stored proc support.

Answer (score 0):

It has some support for it, shown in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions), but it is only syntactic support, since the ActiveRecord replaces the question marks with their values before sending to the database.

Some people ([here](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2007/05/14/unsupport-for-prepared-statements-in-ruby-on-rails/) for example) seem(ed) to be busy with prepared statement support, but no available/working results seem to be integrated into rails yet.